# Почему не выводится таблица

Tags: python, pandas, mac

```
import pandas as pd

url = “https://mfd.ru/centrobank/precious metals/“
print(pd.read_html(url))
```

Comment: а что там по этой ссылке, кроме 404?

Comment: подставьте `url = 'https://mfd.ru/centrobank/preciousmetals/'`

Answer (score 0):

Там было несколько проблем, часть я поправил в самом тексте вопроса, но основная - это неправильный `url`, ну и нужно знать, какую из таблиц брать в результате, тут лучше вторую (с индексом `1`):

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://mfd.ru/centrobank/preciousmetals/"
result = pd.read_html(url)
df = result[1]
```

Содержание `df`:

| index | Дата | Золото руб./грамм | Серебро руб./грамм | Платина руб./грамм | Палладий руб./грамм |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24.11.2022 | 3390.49 | 41.38 | 1939.42 | 3655.14 |
| 1 | 23.11.2022 | 3394.05 | 40.25 | 1920.9 | 3681.89 |
| 2 | 22.11.2022 | 3420.47 | 41.19 | 1925.43 | 3841.09 |
| 3 | 19.11.2022 | 3413.57 | 40.91 | 1917.78 | 3849.14 |
| 4 | 18.11.2022 | 3442.39 | 42.62 | 1974.57 | 4019.04 |
| 5 | 17.11.2022 | 3436.85 | 42.57 | 2000.39 | 4043.47 |
| 6 | 16.11.2022 | 3430.01 | 41.63 | 1964.27 | 3885.88 |
| 7 | 15.11.2022 | 3416.39 | 41.71 | 2019.52 | 3945.83 |
| 8 | 12.11.2022 | 3377.92 | 40.83 | 1970.9 | 3664.94 |
| 9 | 11.11.2022 | 3377.36 | 41.98 | 1955.24 | 3717.51 |
| 10 | 10.11.2022 | 3295.46 | 40.74 | 1923.9 | 3671.11 |

И т.д.